# Uploading data to trimble via pathfinder

Tags: trimble

I was sent via email many different file formats: .dd, .gic, .gip, .gis, .giw, .gix, .obs, .obx, .car

I need to upload this to my trimble to go out and complete a survey. How do you create one "waypoint" file from all of these different formats that can be transferred onto the trimble? Or would it be considered a "data file" when sending the data to the trimble in the data transfer process? Is this whole process completed in pathfinder?

I am new to this process.

Comment: You need to get the data ready in one of the "imported formats" http://trl.trimble.com/docushare/dsweb/Get/Document-145149/13269AC_GPS%20Pathfinder%20Office_DS_1013_LR.pdf

Comment: thank you!  It's that process that I'm unsure of, would this be done in pathfinder?

Comment: Branco, I am playing around in Pathfinder to see if there is a way to combine all different file formats into one shapefile (or another accepted format for trimble upload). However, it is not evident to me. I'm a new to dealing with these different formats.

Answer (score 1):

Those files are what TerraSync actually uses so assuming you have the correct TerraSync version for the SSF files, just copy the set of files into the "My Documents\TerraSync" directory on your data collector and you'll be able to see a data file in TerraSync and open it in TerraSync.

Background:
When you use Pathfinder Office to transfer an SSF or DDF file etc onto your data collector, it splits the SSF into DD and GIC and GIP etc. files.
When you use PFO to transfer a data file from data collector to your PC, it combines the DD and GIC and GOP etc. files into a single SSF file.