# What is a Trimble .CAR file?

Tags: gps, trimble, pathfinder

I have a field team using a Trimble Geo XH from 2008.

My usual workflow is to have them email me the raw GPS files, which I copy into a "GIS Folder" for import to Pathfinder where I process it.  I then transfer the .cor file to that GIS folder.  The output is 8 files that together make the GPS data file. I email the those 8 files to the team to have them copy/paste them on the the GPS unit.

They pointed out to me that the files I sent do not contain a ".CAR" file (no, not ".cor") but there is one currently on the GPS unit. I do not believe I have the ability to recreate a CAR file

What information is in the ".CAR" file?  Can we remove it? Is it important?  Is it optional like .prj .sbn  and other components of a shapefile are?

Edit: I had the team remove the .CAR file from the GPS before copy/pasting the 8 GPS files over. Data collection appeared to go fine all day. By the end of the day when they  backed up the data, the .CAR file had returned, however H-Star processing options are no longer available!

Comment: You should give your field team the [Trimble Data Transfer Utility](http://www.trimble.com/datatransfer/), that will allow them to download an .SSF file from the handheld and email it to you. It's much less error-prone than copying and pasting the separate files. It will also allow them to upload waypoints, background shapefiles, etc. to the unit.

Comment: you can zip the files up to transfer (most likely quicker too)

Comment: very similar question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158576/uploading-data-to-trimble-via-pathfinder

Comment: I guess my initial comment wasn't worded strongly enough: your "usual workflow" is wrong. Stop doing it and use the Trimble Data Transfer Utility instead. Copying and pasting files to and from the handheld is the wrong way to do it.

Comment: Fair enough...the Trimble guy said our way works a few year ago, you say it's wrong (at the very least the transfer utility would be cleaner, certainly). But what information is in the car fle?

Comment: Your way does work, and is often used as a fall-back in case the Trimble data transfer utility doesn't work for some reason, but as you've found, it's prone to causing problems if the wrong files are moved/deleted, which is likely to happen with field crews every once in a while. I don't know what's in the CAR file, I'd guess it's carrier data. You could try opening it in a text editor and taking a look.